# How to create a function in PostgreSQL?

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, create-function

I`ve got only one database which name is "testDB".
In command line:
1)

```
psql testDB
```

2)
create a function as easies as is possible:

```
CREATE or replace FUNCTION testFun()
  RETURNS integer AS $total$
declare
  total integer;
BEGIN
  SELECT count(*) into total FROM "Run";
  RETURN total;
END;
 $$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

I don`t know what it is for?:
     $$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
but it was in some example.

So I copied it to command line.

After all nothing happen.

```
user@LenovoUbuntu:~$ psql testDB 
psql (9.1.11)
Type "help" for help.

testDB=> CREATE or replace FUNCTION testFun()
testDB->   RETURNS integer AS $total$
testDB$> declare
testDB$>   total integer;
testDB$> BEGIN
testDB$>   SELECT count(*) into total FROM "Run";
testDB$>   RETURN total;
testDB$> END;
testDB$>  $$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
testDB$>
```

Pay attention on:

```
testDB=>
testDB->
testDB>
```

Comment: And your question is ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just modify the last line from:

```
 $$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

To

```
 $total$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

You can call your function by

```
Select testFunc();
```

Create function [documentation](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-createfunction.html)

Comment: OK, thank you, but what is it? $total$ LANGUAGE plpgsql; What for?

Comment: Copying examples is not enough - you need to read the [fine](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-createfunction.html) [documentation](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-syntax-lexical.html#SQL-SYNTAX-DOLLAR-QUOTING).

Comment: @andrew Here is why: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-syntax-lexical.html#SQL-SYNTAX-DOLLAR-QUOTING